# Add Text to an XML element

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) file which only has one parent element.

***Content of test.xml file:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>

</Data>
```

In an other file `mytestdata.txt` I have some test data like below that I want to add under the `<Data>` tag.

***Content of mytestdata.txt***

```
This is my data1
This is my data2
This is my data3
```

**Finally the output should be**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
This is my data1
This is my data2
This is my data3
</Data>
```

I am getting the content of `mytestdata.txt` file into a variable one by one now I want to append these values inside `<Data> </Data>` element using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)

What function I should use to append these data under `<Data>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml_text = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>

</Data>
'@

$data_lines = @(
'Data Line 1'
'Data Line 2'
'Data Line 3'
)

$xml = [xml]$xml_text
foreach ($line in $data_lines) {
$xml.Data += $($line + "`r`n")
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $xml.InnerXml
```

to work with files:

```
$xml_text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('file.xml')
$data_lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('file.txt')
```

**UPD01:** If you want to import one XML to another XML, both must be XMLs

```
$xml_text1 = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>

</Data>
'@

$xml_text2 = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootEl>
    <d1>Val1</d1>
    <d2>Val2</d2>
</rootEl>
'@

$xml1 = [xml]$xml_text1
$xml2 = [xml]$xml_text2
#n is new node. 
#Note that it must be imported as we can add nodes only attached to same document. 
#Note that node is attached to document but not places anywhere yet.
$n = $xml1.ImportNode($xml2.DocumentElement,$true);  #true means we are working with external document

#Place a imported node as document root's child
$xml1.DocumentElement.AppendChild($n) | Out-Null

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $xml1.InnerXml
#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Data><rootEl><d1>Val1</d1><d2>Val2</d2></rootEl></Data>
```

Comment: @ filimonic : It worked fine, however if my data file (file.txt as per your code) has "<" or "/>" character, then it is translating to  "&lt;" and "/&gt;". why it is not printing the data as it is

Comment: You can not do this as XML, because your file.txt is not guaranteed to be valid XML until parsed, and every markup symbol will break the whole XML -- that is why special characters are escaped. However, you can add it as CData section: $x = $xml.CreateCDataSection('xxx << yyy '); $xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($x)

Comment: @ filimonic : what If i can guarantee that the file has a valid xml.. actually i am writing the file.txt with valid xml element.. in that case is it possible to avoid the special character ?

Comment: @usr021986 Updated answer to import one xml to another xml.

Answer (score 1):

This will also translating your special characters:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'path_to_test.xml'
$xml.Data = (Get-Content 'path_to_mytestdata.txt') -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
$xml.Save('path_to_test.xml')
```